# Convert a number to an array of items counting down from that number to zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert **5 to [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]**. It is working properly using for loop, here is my snippets,

```
function countDown(startNum) {
  let countDownArray = []
  for(let i = startNum; i >= 0; i-- ){
    countDownArray.push(i)
  }
  return countDownArray
}

console.log(countDown(5));
//expected output: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

I am also trying to solve the problem using ES6, However, there is a bug,
using the following snippets 0 is missing.

```
const values = [...Array(5)].map((_,i) => i+1);
console.log(values);
const reverseValues = [...values].reverse();
console.log(reverseValues);
// output [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
// however expected output [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
// 0 is missing here
```

How can I solve this problem using **ES6**?

Comment: this would work too.
[...Array(n + 1).keys()].reverse()

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

```
const values = [...Array(5)].map((_,i) => i+1);
```

You create an arry of 5 elements, then spread it in a new array, and then map every element to **it's index + 1**.

So if you have 5-elements array, thier indexes will be `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` you map them with +1, so they become `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

### Solution

To achieve your goal you should map array of 6 element to it's indexes without adding 1